# 2D Lock x Axis on character

Tags: unity, c#, unityscript

I am creating an endless runner with a flying character.

I want to lock any movement in the x axis so that the character object can only move up and down but still move forward through the scene. I have looked into freezing axes and joints, but this stops the forward movement.

Is it possible to edit the below to lock the x axis for character movement only, or is there a setting where i can apply this?

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class moveupdown : MonoBehaviour {
    public Vector2 velocity;
    public float uservelocity;
    public Rigidbody2D rb2D;

    void Start() {
        rb2D = GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();
    }

    void FixedUpdate() {        

        if (Input.touchCount > 0 && Input.GetTouch (0).phase == TouchPhase.Moved) {
            Vector2 touchDeltaPosition = Input.GetTouch (0).deltaPosition;

            rb2D.MovePosition (rb2D.position + touchDeltaPosition * Time.fixedDeltaTime / uservelocity);

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I have tried rigid body constraints too, but they stop any x axis movement, meaning my character is not able to move through the scene at all

Answer (score 1):

Don't take deltaPosition.x value:

```
Vector2 touchDeltaPosition = new Vector2(0, Input.GetTouch(0).deltaPosition.y);
```

Comment: Thanks Adrian,

I am now not able to move along x axis, great!

However, x movement freezes when i move the character up and down, once i remove my finger he starts moving along x again.

Comment: @Gary If you add this delta position to the calculated x delta per frame, you should will not be frozen in the x axis.